# Creating custom layout only in xml vs creating view in xml + java

Tags: java, android, xml

I've created custom layouts in XML and then inflated it into other views (into listView with inflater or into my activity using include for example) and everything works fine but later I noticed all guides for creating a custom View include java code (example: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)
so my question is: what's the difference? do I must make the code? how will it benefit?

Comment: Custom View means a UI component (subclass of View or ViewGroup) other than the ones provided in the Android SDK. You cannot make a custom view only in XML--that's just a layout file. You make a custom view if you need something with different behavior than anything in the SDK.

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant: I created several layouts, inflated into list view and second one into another layout that is my activity (going to edit my question)

Comment: If the layouts do exactly what you want, then you don't need to do anything else. As stated in my previous comment, you write custom views when you need specific behavior that is not supported by what is provided in the SDK. Just because you found some guides on the internet does not mean they are guides for the thing you want.